# wso2 apimanager quick start issue

Tags: wso2

I have just started to explore the apimanager and am following the quick start guide.

When I get to implement phase and put in the phoneverify url in the production endpoint and press "test" I get the message "invalid", however if I put it directly in my browser, it works fine.

I get this behaviour for the WSDL as well.

Then if I try to save it, I get cannot be saved and throws lots of error messages

Anybody any pointers

Clemo

org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while adding the API- PhoneVerification-1.0.0 (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#50) at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754) at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148) at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:50) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430) at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269) at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_31(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:101) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_2(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:231) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:18) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag) at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394) at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag) at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag) at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570) at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936) at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while adding the API- PhoneVerification-1.0.0 at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.handleException(APIProviderHostObject.java:128) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:731) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updateAPIImplementation(APIProviderHostObject.java:474) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126) ... 56 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while updating the API :PhoneVerification at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:687) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:570) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:58) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:727) ... 62 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:687) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:706) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:486) ... 64 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to reset the WSDL : http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:1102) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:629) ... 65 more Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:104) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:1082) ... 66 more Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2324) at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2272) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:129) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:85) ... 67 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) at

Comment: what is the version that your trying ?

Comment: Could you sort this out?